# Installed Ubuntu after Windows 10, no boot options whatsoever

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I have been spending the last few days reading the possible solutions and they are either not working for me or they require a computer knowledge above my own.

Like the title says I partitioned the drive and installed Ubuntu after Windows 10 was already there. The installation went smoothly but whenever I start the computer I get no boot options, the system boots straight into Windows 10.

Is there a relatively easy way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe there is... First of all you should check the boot order in the UEFI settings and select "ubuntu" instead of "windows bootloader manager".

Comment: Thank you, already tried that. Unfortunately there is NO "Ubuntu" option, just "Windows Bootloader Manager."

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide details about the manufacturer of your computer and describe what you have already tried. You might also want to check out [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode? If not, you might want to try that as well. If you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode and have secure boot enabled on your PC, you might want to try to manually select grubx64.efi file as trusted (if your BIOS has such option).

Comment: Reboot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode, and install Boot-Repair again. Then in advanced mode do the full uninstall/reinstall of grub. That will install the UEFI boot version of grub-efi-amd64. You installed a BIOS boot version into the partition boot sector which is not recommended and will not boot in your configuration.

Comment: We did it guys, thank you so much! I re-installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode to finally get the "Ubuntu" option displayed in the UEFI menu. I also had to change the option in the UEFI from "Secure Boot > UEFI Windows" to "Secure Boot > Other OS" in order to be able to boot Ubuntu, otherwise it would just freeze. Thank you again, since this was just the beginning I am sure you'll hear from me again soon enough! XD

Comment: I am glad that your problem has been resolved. Could you just please copy the edit to your question to the answer box below and mark it as accepted so that this post would be properly tracked as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode to finally get the "Ubuntu" option displayed in the UEFI menu. I also had to change the option in the UEFI from "Secure Boot > UEFI Windows" to "Secure Boot > Other OS" in order to be able to boot Ubuntu, otherwise it would just freeze.